# GitHub orphan commits or history due to connectivity issues

Tags: git, version-control, github

Today I tried to synchronize **master** and **develop** branches. The code is in a private repository in GitHub. Im using the git workflow described here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Before the sync I've merged a **hotfix** branch to **master**:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/xxx/xxx
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

$ git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.

$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git merge --no-ff master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 test.file | 2 ++
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)

$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

When I tried to push my local develop branch to remote I got this error:

```
$ git push origin develop
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 232 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=7, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

then I tried again and got this error:

```
$ git push origin develop
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/': Failed connect to github.com:443; Operation timed out
```

Looking at the GitHub web interface I see:
[image]
Verifying with Git CLI on local terminal:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git log --oneline master..develop
12rt21t Merge branch 'master' into develop
12rth1t Merge branch 'master' into develop
```

---

My question are:

1) Should I be worried?

2) How can I fix this?

3) What does **This branch is 2 commits ahead and 0 commits behind master** mean?

Thanks!

Comment: GitHub was 'offline' for about an hour due to some ddos-ing today, could that be related to the problem?

Comment: I figured that this could be the issue. Anyway this scenario can repeat so I think is useful to know how the 'leftovers' can be cleaned up :)